# Subequation aligning using matrix

Tags: equations, align, matrices, subequations

When I use multiple matrix equations in subequation, I am doing it as in the code snippet. However, when I want to align the equations with respect to ***equal sign, =*** (commented in the code), I am having errors during `pdftex`ing.

Is there an alternative way to align the subequations?

```
\begin{subequations}
%\begin{align}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:model_m}
    [M] =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    m_{1} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & m_{2} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & m_{3} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:model_c}
    [C] =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1} + c_{2} & -c_{2} & 0\\
    -c_{2} & c_{2}+ c_{3} & -c_{3}\\
    0 & -c_{3} & c_{3} \\
    \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{equation} 
%\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

A minimal example would be (thanks to suggestion from Svend Tveskæg):

```
\documentclass[]{report}   % list options between brackets
\usepackage{amsmath} %contains the advanced math extensions for LaTeX

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
%\begin{align}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:model_m}
    [X] =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 \\
    0 & b \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:model_c}
    [Y] =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    c+e & 0\\
    0 & d+f
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 
%\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Edit: For reference, I am using MiKTeX and TeXstudio on Windows 7, if it matters.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). How do you want to align the matrices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `equation` within `align`, so just remove all those, add `&` before the equals signs, and add a line break (`\\`) at the end of the first line (after the matrix) and this works just fine.

```
\documentclass[]{report}   % list options between brackets
\usepackage{amsmath} %contains the advanced math extensions for LaTeX

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
 \label{eq:model_m}
    [X] &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 \\
    0 & b \\
    \end{bmatrix} \\
 \label{eq:model_c}
    [Y] &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    c+e & 0\\
    0 & d+f
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: didn't know it could be that easy. what does & sign do specifically for this case?

Comment: @Ali The `&` defines the alignment point. `align` doesn't magically know where you want to align things, so you define that by adding `&` just before the equals sign. See e.g. [`amsmath`s manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `equation` environment inside `align`. `Align` already contains the capabilities.

```
\documentclass[]{report}   % list options between brackets
\usepackage{mathtools} %Fixes/improves amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:all}
\begin{align}
\label{eq:model_m}
    [X] &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & 0 \\
    0 & b \\
    \end{bmatrix}\\
\label{eq:model_c}
    [Y] &=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    c+e & 0\\
    0 & d+f
    \end{bmatrix}
%\end{equation} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Some \eqref{eq:all},\eqref{eq:model_c},\eqref{eq:model_m}
\end{document}
```

[image]